# How to change indentation for formatting Dart in Android Studio 2022?

Tags: android-studio, dart

In previous versions it was possible to do this. But now Android Studio relies on DartFmt to do the formatting of Dart, hence it's no longer possible.
Can one change which formatter Android Studio should use or is there some other way to "hack" dartfmt which doesn't allow indentation to be set?

Comment: Well, Android Studio, the Dart and Flutter plugins, and `dartfmt` are all open-source. It is therefore possible to change anything - it just depends on how much effort you put in to doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't think that it is a possible solution though, because there is a stipulated reason for such things as code indentation to not change: They want Dart code to look the same wherever you go, for legibility. It's group interest over individual preference, they say. So... it's by design, not by lack of effort by the open source community.

Comment: I meant, there's nothing stopping you modifying tooling to fit your own needs. You don't need those modifications to be upstreamed and included in public releases.

Comment: Yes, that is of course a possibility. I will go through the existing forks of dart-lang/dart-style to see if anybody has already done it. Thanks :)